# Function to concatenate two strings in C using strlen but without using strcat

Tags: c, concatenation, c-strings, strlen, function-definition

I need to concatenate the strings `"abc"` and `"def"` using `strlen` but without using `strcat`. Can someone show me what is wrong with my `main()` function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void strconcatenate(char *string1, char *string2) {
    int i;
    int j = strlen(string1);
    for (i = 0; string2[i]; i++) {
        string1[i+j] = string2[i];
    }
    string1[i + j]= '\0';
}

int main() {
    char string1[3] = "abc";
    string1[strlen(string1) - 1] = '\0';
    char string2[3] = "def";
    string2[strlen(string2) - 1] = '\0';

    strconcatenate(string1, string2);  
    printf("Resultant string = %s\n", string1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string1[3]` is only big enough for string `"ab"`, not `"abc"` and not `"abcdef"`.

Comment: You dont get a warning in this line? char string1[3] = "abc";  "abc" is 4 chars, the \0 is already included by the compiler. So the 0 assignment is also useless.

Comment: What makes you think that something is wrong?

Comment: Can you use functions other than `strlen`? If so, it'll be easy enough.

Comment: The line `char string1[3] = "abc";` is valid C. It creates an array of size 3 that contains the characters 'a', 'b', and 'c'. But that array is **not** a string, just an array of 3 characters. So calling `strlen(string1)` is invalid and results in undefined behavior.

Comment: i changed it to string1[4] and string2[4] but the out put is just "Resultant string is " and thats it

Comment: I GOT IT ty for the help

Comment: Please create an answer, maybe [edit] the question so that it matches the answer you create. Try to apply [ask] and [answer]. Also, please take the [tour].

Comment: Brendan McCann, if you do not want to make a nice Q/A pair by creating an answer and polishing both, then please delete this question; because otherwise it is unlikely to become a contribution to StackOverflows goal of a helpful Q/A collection.

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen: Actually, the C compiler isn't allowed to reject the initializer; it must accept `char string1[3] = "abc";` and in this circumstance, the byte array is not null-terminated.  It can complain, but the code is compliant with Standard C and must be accepted.  A C++ compiler must complain about this.  See C11 [§6.7.9 Initialization ¶14](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14).

Comment: ah ye of course. it's more a lint kind of thing I guess

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen: Especially for character arrays that are nested in other structures, the ability to express strings without a trailing zero byte is very useful if not critical.  What's unfortunate is the lack of any syntax to distinguish between arrays that are expected to be zero-terminated, zero-padded if necessary, or neither (i.e. are expected to have their entire contents explicitly specified).

Answer (score 3):

In main you declared character arrays with three elements

```
char string1[3] = "abc";
//...
char string2[3] = "def";
```

These arrays do not contain strings because they do not store the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literals used as initializers. The first array contains three characters `{ 'a', 'b', 'c' }` and the second array contains these three characters `{ 'd', 'e', 'f' }`.

Then you applied the standard string function `strlen` to these arrays which expects that passed to it arrays contains strings. That is the function calculates the number of characters in a string by counting characters until the terminating zero character is encountered. As the arrays do not contain the terminating zero character '\0' that is as the arrays do not contain strings the calls of `strlen` invoke undefined behavior.

If you want to append one string to another string then the destination character array shall have enough size to be able to accommodate the second string.

Thus the function main can look the following way

```
int main( void ) {
    char string1[7] = "abc";
    char string2[] = "def";

    printf( "Resultant string = %s\n", strconcatenate( string1, string2 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Now the both arrays `string1` and `string2` contain strings. Moreover the array `string1` reserved enough space to accommodate the string stored in the array `string2`.

The declaration of the function `strconcatenate` should be similar to the declaration of the standard C function `strcat`.

```
char * strconcatenate( char *string1, const char *string2 );
```

That is the second parameter should have the qualifier `const` because the passed array is not changed within the function and the function should return the destination array that will contain the concatenated strings.

The function definition will look the following way

```
char * strconcatenate( char *string1, const char *string2 ) 
{
    for ( char *p = string1 + strlen( string1 ); *p++ = *string2++; );

    return string1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- **[major]** `char string1[3] = "abc";` defines the destination array with a size of 3 bytes which does not have a enough space for the string `"abc"` including its null terminator and definitely not long enough to receive the extra characters from `string2` at the end. Change this to `char string1[7] = "abc";`
- **[major]** `char string2[3] = "def";` defines the source array with a size of 3 bytes which does not have a enough space for the string `"def"` including its null terminator, hence will not be null terminated.
- **[major]** `string1[strlen(string1) - 1] = '\0';` overwrites the last character of `abc`, this not necessary.
- **[major]** same remark for `string2[strlen(string2) - 1] = '\0';`
- **[minor]** `string2` should be defined as `const char *` in `void strconcatenate(char *string1, char *string2)`
- **[minor]** `i` and `j` should be defined with type `size_t`
- **[minor]** for compatibility with the standard function `strcat`, `strconcatenate` should have a return type of `char *` and return the pointer to the destination array. Yet, As commented by *Jonathan Leffler*, a more useful design for the return value is to return a pointer to the null at the end of the concatenated string. You already know where the start of the string is; that isn't very interesting information. But knowing where the end of the string is after concatenation — that is useful information which only the concatenate function is privy to. –

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strconcatenate(char *string1, const char *string2) {
    char *p = string1 + strlen(string1);
    while ((*p = *string1) != '\0') {
        string1++;
        p++;
    }
    return string1;  /* strcat semantics */
    //return p;      /* alternative semantics */
}

int main() {
    char string1[7] = "abc";
    char string2[] = "def";

    strconcatenate(string1, string2);
    printf("Resultant string = %s\n", string1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A more useful design for the return value is to return a pointer to the null at the end of the concatenated string.  You already know where the start of the string is; that isn't very interesting information.  But knowing where the end of the string is after concatenation — that is useful information which only the concatenate function is privy to.  Of course, a drop-in replacement for `strcat()` must return the pointer to the destination string because that's what `strcat()` does — but the design of `strcat()` isn't as useful as it could/should be.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: good point. Funny POSIX does not have `stpcat` coined from `stpcpy`, with a trivial implementation: `return stpcpy(dst + strlen(dst), src);`

Comment: There is room to argue that by the time you know it is safe to concatenate two strings, you can use one of the memory copy functions instead of `strcat()`, and you know where the end of the result is.  You have to know the size of the destination array, the length of what's already in it and the length of what you are going to add to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since string1 and string2 has 3 characters so you need to declare it with 4 bytes('\0') and also when you need not to subtract 1 from strlen because it points to '\0' character.
Below is the change to the code.

```
int main()
{
  char string1[4] = "abc";
  string1[strlen(string1)] = '\0';
  char string2[4] = "def";
  string2[strlen(string2)] = '\0';

  strconcatenate(string1,string2);  
  printf("Resultant string = %s\n",string1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 4 bytes is not enough for `string1`: `strconcatenate` will write 4 bytes at the end of the string in `string1`.